# PHP runs a storing procedure on a database, how can I see concrete parameters passed into without altering source code?

Tags: php, google-chrome, debugging

Here is `php` code:

```
$query = Container::get('db_connection')
    ->prepare('sp_Util_SearchMemberByKeyWord');

$query->bind('szSort', $searchcol, DatabaseTypes::NVARCHAR(100))
    ->bind('szKeyWord', $searchstr, DatabaseTypes::NVARCHAR(100))
    ->bind('partnerid', $partnerid, DatabaseTypes::INT)
    ->bind('hideDisabled', $hideDisabled, DatabaseTypes::INT)
    ->bind('hideDemo', $hideDemo, DatabaseTypes::INT)
    ->bind('hideByLmtdAccountManagerUserID', 
$hideByLimitedAccountManagerUserID, DatabaseTypes::NVARCHAR(100))
    ->execute();
```

I need to see exact values of the params passed into the storing procedure. There is no way I can debug or alter source code. Google Chrome (or any other browser) seems to be only one option. I also got access to the appropriate database. Can I capture those values somehow using built-in Chrome functionality or some advanced features of SQL Management Studio?

P.S. I am not `php` dev, not at all.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to see variables in PHP is using the `var_dump();` and `exit;`
Use it before your code.
For example:

```
var_dump($searchcol); exit;
```

Comment: I think that there is no way to display these variables only by using the browser